# Gitlab and multiple merge requests for already merged branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

In project we have `feature` branch (everyone can have own branch like this) and `master`, which is the final one. Also we have two different projects: one for building the app which contains branching model as described above. And second project just for the deployment, where we are passing the docker image, which should be used. So basically all changes made on master are not automatically deployed to the server.

I would like to know what we should do in following scenario:

`Feature_A` branch is merged into master by 'Merge request' . After that someone else committed and pushed something into master. Error has been found in `Feature_A`, so creator of this branch pushed new changes to this branch and again merged into master using 'Merge request'.

And now in history of commits we have two positions `Merge branch 'Feature_A' into 'master'` divided in time (like hours). It doesn't look good and I was wondering what we could do with it... Can we revert all unnecessary `Merge`'s and create the final one? I would like to add that some people already rebased on master.

Comment: Why are you worried about whether it looks good? Maybe consider not letting anyone just merge to master and implement a pull-request strategy.

Comment: My bad, it has been merged thanks to 'Merge request', but we didn't notice the problem at this moment.

Comment: I still don’t see a need to fret over “unnecessary merges”. Be still and know that they don’t matter.

Answer (score 1):

Not only can you do it (merge Feature A twice), but you can include the previously merged commit for context now:

See [GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#review-previously-merged-commits-in-merge-requests) (March 2022)

> ### Review previously merged commits in merge requests
>
> The best code reviews take into account the broader context and impact of changes, including previously merged commits. But it can be challenging to bring that context into merge requests, so that everyone can discuss how the proposed changes align with older changes.
>
> You can now stack previously merged commits onto the proposed changes in your merge request, to help you and everyone else understand the full context of the changes.
>
> Thanks to [Paulo Vitor Magacho](https://gitlab.com/pvmagacho), [Anwar Sadath](https://gitlab.com/asadath1395) and [Abhishek Kumar](https://gitlab.com/akumar1503) for all working to contribute this!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_9/code-review-context-commits-merge-requests.png -- Review previously merged commits in merge requests]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/commits.html#view-merge-request-commits-in-context) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29274).